# Adding Multiple Values into a Column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, jupyter-notebook

I have two pandas dataframes that Im trying to merge together on their ID number. However in df1 the ID is being used multiple times and in df2 it is only being used once. Therefore I want the final dataframe to include all the results seperated by commas and having a index value in front of it. I made a simple example that will help me explain what I'm asking.

**df1:**
[image: picture of dataframe 1]

**df2:**
[image]

**Merged Goal:**
[image]

Ive tried merging them how I usually do:

```
MergedGoal= pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')
```

But I get a key error for ID, probably because there are duplicates. How can I add them together? and if anyone could also give me some insight as how to add an index for each value added that would be amazing. But if its not possible to add the index numbers thats totally fine, I just need all of the values in the same entry seperated by commas.

Comment: please no images, post the data as text

Comment: Why whats wrong with images?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Oh I see why images are bad

Comment: Sure , Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: @carsandcoding first step is probably to check what `df1.columns` and `df2.columns` show you - make sure they both have something called exactly "ID" and don't have trailing spaces or something... that's a common gotcha. (eg: one could be called `ID` and the other `ID ` - or something similarly subtle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created *df1* the following way:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 1, 'Manchester', 'NH',  3108 ],
    [ 1, 'Bedford',    'NH',  3188 ],
    [ 6, 'Boston',     'MA', 23718 ],
    [ 1, 'Austin',     'TX', 20034 ]],
    columns=['ID', 'City', 'State', 'Zip'])
df1.Zip = df1.Zip.astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```

Note that I changed source *Zip*s (as I see, they are "plain"
integers) to a *string*, because you want to have leading zeroes.

To create *df2* I used:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[ 1, 'Best Cities', 'xxx' ], [ 6, 'Worst Cities', 'yyy' ]],
    columns=['ID', 'Title', 'Description'])
```

As a preparation step, let's define a function, which will be used
to aggregate columns from *df1*:

```
def fn(src):
    lst = [ f'{idx}) {val}' for idx, val in enumerate(src, start=1) ]
    return ', '.join(lst)
```

The first step of this function is a *list comprehension*, where
*enumerate* iterates over *src* (the content of the current column
in the current group) and substitutes:

- *idx* - the current element index, but starting from 1,
- *val* - the current element itself.

Formatting of result items performs *f-string*.
The result is a list of e.g. city names with numbers before them.

*return* statement joins this list into a string, inserting ", "
between them.

So e.g. for group for *ID == 1* and *City* column, the source values are:
`[ 'Manchester', 'Bedford', 'Austin' ]` and result is:
`1) Manchester, 2) Bedford, 3)Austin`.

And the actual processing can be performed with a **single** instruction:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1.groupby('ID').agg(fn), how='left',
    left_on='ID', right_index=True).fillna('')
```

As you can see:

- I reverted the order of merged DataFrames. This way the result
  contains first columns from *df2*, then from *df1*.
- *City*, *State*  and *Zip* columns from *df1* are first
  grouped by *ID* and aggregated, using *fn* function.
- Then they are merged with *df2*.
- I added *fillna('')* to replace *NaN* values with an empty string,
  which would occur in case of *ID*s present only in *df2*.

Comment: Hey thank you so much! It does exactly what I need. I'm just trying to understand how the def fn(src) function works. I am still kinda new at Python, do you think you could explain what it does in a couple of sentences just so I have a better understanding of what is actually happening?

Comment: I added description of the aggregation function (*fn*). Maybe you should read a little about *list comprehensions* and *f-strings*. Search the Web, you will certainly find a lot of descriptions, even on StackOverflow.